# Is there another way to filter subviews by class except enumerate and check?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, subview

First of all, by filtering, means finding all the (targetClass) views in the subviews.

Normally, if we want to filter subviews by class, we probably do:

```
// Create an array to hold them
NSMutableArray *filteredViews = [NSMutableArray new];

// enumerate and check
for (UIView *view in parentView.subviews) {
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[targetClass class]) {
        [filteredViews addObject:view];
    }
}
```

Is this the proper way to do it?

Does Cocoa Touch have a dedicated method to filter subviews?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by filtering subviews. Can you explain what you want to do.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? In the developer docs Apple recommends to either store pointers to the views you need to modify (e.g. using properties) or to identify a view by its tag. And that would be a cleaner solution in most cases. → [Locating Views in a View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate to define a rule to select the items you want. Note I'm using `isKindOfClass`, and not `isMemberOfClass`, since the former takes class hierarchy into account, and will be able to identify subclasses of the class you are looking for.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [targetClass class]];
NSArray* filteredViews= [parentView.subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I want!